# How can I querying a key value without retriving all data in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

I'm learning angularjs, firebase, angularfire by building a sample app. It's a dictionary app that any one can add a word, add several explanation to the word, add several common usage to the word, add example centences to the word. People can freely add new word via this web app. OR people can freely realtime search a word and display the content of that word. When I build the app.

I found everytime when I search a word, I have to load all the data and then check if the query string exist in the data and then display the content if exist. So, it's quite heavy if the library become very big.

How can I query a string if it exist from the server side and if exist, just download that piece of data?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example that is on the firebase site ([Retreiving data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html)). I suggest you take a look at that page, there is a lot more info there about this subject. Now the example:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs");
ref.orderByChild([the child node to compare to]).equalTo([what you are searching]).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  //do something with the data in snapshot
});
```